# get sum of values within fixed date window

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql

I've got the dataset and i want to get `result` column.

[image: desired result]

Following logic:

The data partitioned by `cust` and `form` fields.

For each partition, for every row i'm checking previous rows withing given interval (e.g. in this case 1 month) and add up values from 'exist_flg' column.

Is there any solution of this problem using sql or perhaps pandas ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want a window function with a `range` window frame specification:

```
select t.*,
       sum(exist_flg) over (partition by cust, from
                            order by date
                            range between interval '1 month' preceding and current row)
                           ) as result
from t;
```

Comment: i've thought about row/range clause, but didn't know that it accepts intervals. Much Thanks